# I2C slave device address bouncing around

Tags: sensor, raspberry-pi, i2c

I am interfacing an [SHT20](https://www.sensirion.com/fileadmin/user_upload/customers/sensirion/Dokumente/2_Humidity_Sensors/Datasheets/Sensirion_Humidity_Sensors_SHT20_Datasheet.pdf) with a Raspberry Pi via I2C.

In Linux, I am using i2cdetect from the i2c-tools package.

The issue is that I'm expecting to see a static address in this table, but instead I am seeing multiple addresses. More specifically, every time I run the command, I get a different output. Sometimes I get no addresses, sometimes I get a random address. Below is my command output. All three commands were run within a couple of seconds.

```
root@test-pi:~# i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- 26 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
root@test-pi:~# i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
root@test-pi:~# i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:          -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- 74 -- -- --
```

On the electronics side, I'm using 10k pullups, 100nF across VDD and VSS, and feeding 3V3. **Note that below, I'm mounting the sensor upside down, the way it's shown in the datasheet at the top of section 3, hence the image showing pins 1+6 as not connected. They are going to the correct location.**

[image: circuit]
[image: irlpcb]

In the attached oscilloscope screenshot, CH1 is my SCL and CH2 is my SDA.

[image: waveform]

Firstly, not sure why SCL comes to two different levels on the low end, I was expecting a more consistent waveform on SCL. Secondly, my SDA doesn't look like data - it more or less just follows SCL.

Do those waveforms look kosher? Is there a signal that I need to be sending from the master before looking for the address (Section 5.2 of the datasheet mentions a start/stop sequence, but I think the kernel driver handles that automatically)? Are there any other measurements that would help me figure out what is going on?

Comment: This long comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore it is going to be moved to, and should be continued in, chat (link below). --- As this moving of comments to chat can only be done once, any further comments posted here which try to clarify and understand the question, might be deleted without notice. **Keep it in chat, please!** When someone has got enough information from the chat to post a valid answer, then please do that. Any factual updates to the question which are decided during the chat, should be made via an edit to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123885/discussion-on-question-by-md-7-i2c-slave-device-address-bouncing-around).

Answer (score 2):

The pins are connected wrong in the schematic.

According to the datasheet, the pins for SDA and SCL are 1 & 6.

In the schematic you connect them to 3 & 4.

The same applies to supply pins 2 & 5. Datasheet says 2 is ground and 5 is VDD.

Comment: I was trying to avoid posting the schematic for this reason... I remapped the pin assignments in the footprint. The PCB layout picture is the more accurate thing to look at. I'm mounting it upside down as well. Just silly prototype things. You can see in the PCB layout that SDA/SCL does actually go to pins 1/6.

Comment: @MD-7 It would have been polite of you to add all of this information to your question. As it is you have everyone running around chasing ghosts.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson You're right. I'll remove that image, it only adds confusion

Comment: @MD-7 I don't get it - is blue on top like it seems, or on bottom? If blue is on top, when you place the IC on top of PCB and rotate SDA/SCL pins to point down, you have GND&VDD swapped, and SDA&SCL swapped. Regardless of pin numbers.

Comment: @Justme No, blue is the bottom layer. So you need to flip in the x direction as well.

Comment: @MD-7 Why would you design blue bottom layer on top and some other layer (red, top) behind it? Please take a photo of the PCB, showing the SHT20 sensor and traces around it.

Comment: @Justme I added the photo of the PCB. And that's not a design choice, the PCB software will show you the layer you're currently working on as being in front. Otherwise, my top layer ground plane would just obscure your vision of everything there on the bottom layer, which would be pretty silly.

Comment: @MD-7 the chip orientation looks correct. But the photo does not show the orientation how it is connected to the RPi header. The pinout numbering is clearly wrong too, RPi has 3V3, SDA, SCL on pins 1,3,5, but your connector connects them to pins 2,4,6, as the square pin is pin 1. Also, where does the ground trace from the chip go to, does it connect to RPi ground? That is not visible either.